# Parsing JSON with JQ using numerical key

Tags: json, jq

I have a below curl which passes the value `2000` in the jq command which returns the right value...

```
curl -X GET \
  -H 'vmware-api-session-id: <auth-id>' \
  -k -s
  'https://<url>/api/vcenter/vm/vm-22' | python -m json.tool | jq -r '.disks."2000" | .label, .capacity' | paste - -

Hard disk 1 52143587328
```

Now I have this `2000` part of a variable. Like `i=2000`
And jq like

```
jq -r '.disks."$i"
```

returns

```
null null
```

I am unable to figure out how to pass this `2000` via a variable

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
jq -r --arg i "$i" '.disks[$i] | [ .label, .capacity ] | @tsv'
```

This passes the shell variable `i` into the `jq` expression as the *`jq` variable* `$i` (which is a string).  You use this as a key with `[$i]`.

I've also removed the need to use `paste` by using `@tsv` on an array containing the two values you want in `jq` instead.  This would produce tab-delimited output, as would your `paste` command.

You also should not need to pass the data through `python -m json.tool` (I don't see what benefit this has).  If it was used for pretty-printing, then that is not needed for input into `jq`.

---

Looking at [the VMware API documentation](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm/vm/hardware/disk/disk/get/), the request to get information about a specific disk looks like

```
https://{api_host}/api/vcenter/vm/{vm}/hardware/disk/{disk}
```

This makes me think that you should be using `vm-22` in place of `{vm}` and `2000` (or `"$i"`) in place of `{disk}`, `vm-22` is the name of you virtual machine and `2000` is your disk identifier.

This should give you something like

```json
{
    "backing": {
        "type": "enum",
        "vmdk_file": "string"
    },
    "capacity": 0,
    "ide": {
        "master": false,
        "primary": false
    },
    "label": "string",
    "sata": {
        "bus": 0,
        "unit": 0
    },
    "scsi": {
        "bus": 0,
        "unit": 0
    },
    "type": "enum"
}
```

as a response.

You can parse the label and capacity out from this as a tab-delimited list, using

```bsh
jq -r '[ .label, .capacity ] | @tsv'
```

Comment: The `python -m json.tool` was there for me to interpret some output nicely in pretty print. Wont actually exist in the script...Though the above command returns
```jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.disks.[$i] | [ .label, .capacity] | @tsv```

Comment: `jq -r --arg i "$j" '.disks | .[$i] | [.label, .capacity]|@tsv'` This worked
Even this
`jq -r --arg i "$i" '.disks | .[$i] | [.label, .capacity]|@tsv'`

Comment: @Suhas Sorry, fixed now. No dot before `[$i]`.  You can pretty print with `jq .` (in place of that `python` I mean).

Comment: What's the point of fiddling about with `jq` instead of just using `sed` or any other standard tool?

Comment: @Kitsos JSON is not a line-oriented document format (so whitespace, including newlines, between values are not significant), and it may contain specially encoded values that may need decoding (if reading) or encoding (if writing). `sed` can definitely cope with all of this, but it would mean having to implement a JSON parser in `sed` to do it correctly. It is more convenient, safer, and makes for code that is easy to maintain to use `jq`.